# R change character encoding of a character vector

Tags: r, excel, encoding, utf-8

I read in two data frames from two different excel spreadsheets using  openxlsx::read.xlsx. I want to get the common column names. With

```
intersect(colnames(nutrients), colnames(req.EAR))
```

the output is

```
[1] "carbohydrate_g" "calcium_mg"     "iron_mg"        "magnesium_mg"   "phosphorus_mg"  "zinc_mg"        "vit_c_mg"      
[8] "thiamin_mg"     "riboflavin_mg"  "niacin_mg"      "vit_b6_mg"      "folate_µg"      "vit_b12_µg"     "vit_a_rae_µg"  
[15] "vit_e_mg"
```

a common element - vit_d_μg - doesn't show up in the intersection. I suspected this was because in both spreadsheets, element that contain μ are coded as UTF-8 while the rest are "unknown".

The cause of all of this I think is the mu (μ) in the column name. I originally thought this was due to the fact that element names with mu in it were encoded as UTF-8 while the others were "unknown".

The real reason is that there are two UTF-8 characters that look like mu. At this website ([http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm]

```
GREEK SMALL LETTER MU (U+03BC) looks like μ.
MICRO SIGN (U+00B5) looks like µ.
```

Someone (probably me) made a mistake in adding the mu to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm a fan of `stringi::stri_trans_general(names(df), 'Any-Latin')`, which sorts out most anything that can cause a problem.

Comment: Post `dput( colnames(nutrients))` and `dput( colnames(req.EAR))`